# jQuery to dynamically pass in an element's ID to limit the scope of slideToggle()

Tags: jquery, slidetoggle

In the script below, I'm trying to pass in a reference to the parent container's ID in order to limit the scope of the slideToggle to that element's child elements whose class matches.

How can I alter the code to pass in the ID? The problem is that '***myID*** .extras' is apparently not the proper syntax.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function()
{
    jQuery(document).on('click','.toggleExtras', function(e){
        var myEl = jQuery(this).closest('.widget');
        var myID = jQuery(myEl).attr('id');
        jQuery('myID .extras').slideToggle();
        jQuery(this).text(function(el, old){
            return old == "Show Advanced Options" ? "Hide Advanced Options" : "Show Advanced Options";
        });
    });

});
```

HTML:

```
<div id="widget-43_my_box_cats-4" class="widget">   
    <div class="widget-top">
        <div class="widget-title-action"></div>
        <div class="widget-title"><h4>Widget Title<span class="in-widget-title"></span></h4></div>
    </div>

    <div class="widget-inside" style="display: block;">
        <form action="" method="post">
            <div class="widget-content">
                <p>
                    <label for="widget-my_box_cats-4-title">Title:</label>
                    <input class="widefat" id="widget-my_box_cats-4-title" name="widget-my_box_cats[4][title]" type="text" value="">
                </p>

                <fieldset><legend><span class="toggleExtras">Hide Advanced Options</span></legend>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why get the ID, and do a lot of beating around the bush, when you can just find the element directly:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    jQuery(document).on('click','.toggleExtras', function(e){

        jQuery(this).closest('.widget').find('.extras').slideToggle();

        jQuery(this).text(function(el, old){
            return old == "Show Advanced Options" ? "Hide Advanced Options" : "Show Advanced Options";
        });
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

`jQuery('myID .extras').slideToggle();` should be `jQuery('#myID .extras').slideToggle();`

For [id selecor](http://api.jquery.com/id-selector/) you need to use the prefix `#`. `myID` is an [element selector](http://api.jquery.com/element-selector/) where it will look for elements with tag-name `myID`